# Cordova geolocation service not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build a cordaova application using React on front-end.

I am using [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/) plugin.

When I start the app on my emulator. It asks permission for location.

[image]

But when I give the permission I am getting time-out error :

[image]

I have initialized the react app like this :

```js
const startApp = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
}
    
if(!window.cordova) {
    startApp()
} else {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', startApp, false)
}
```

I am calling location services in `ComponentDidMount()` lifecycle method as :

```js
function onSuccess(position) {
    this.setState({
      locationLat : position.coords.latitude,
      locationLng : position.coords.longitude
    });
}

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

    // Options: throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds.
    //
var watchID = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess.bind(this), onError, { timeout: 30000 });
```

What could be the reason for this error ?
How can I fix it ?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Have you tested if your emulator can return GPS data? Maybe launch the Google Maps.

Comment: @JamesWong My emulator is not showing geolocation. I just tested on android device at [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/). I am getting same error.

Comment: I think the issue comes from your emulator. Make sure geolocation is on and try on another emulator or with a physical device,